# How to correctly use the thermal conductivity coefficient formula?

Tags: civil-engineering, thermal-conduction, thermal-insulation

I'm trying to help a friend.

We are trying to use the formula below to calculate the thermal conductivity coefficient of a composite material (styro-bamboo).

Q=100 Watts, d (or thickness)= 20mm, A= 200 x 200 mm. Using a hotbox, the cold temp was 34.5C and hot temp was 89.3C.

Given the data, we could not get a result that is at least below 0.05 W/mK. And given the temperature range, achieving that seems impossible (it would require a temperature difference of about 5000!). However, the published paper below seems to have achieved the said thermal conductivity values despite the average temperature range of their testing box (around 90C).

I was wondering if we used the formula wrong and if anyone can show us how the said paper got their values. Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Link to the Paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.18052/www.scipress.com/IJET.17.21

[image: Thermal conducitivity formula]

Attempted solution:
[image]

Comment: Your formula is fine. The issue is that your boundary conditions may not be. Heat may be finding another path from hot to cold. You should repeat with smaller area, bigger thickness, and so forth unless you have a good model of how heat is flowing. Also don't believe everything you read...

Comment: If the thermocouples measure fluid temperature, you may need to include heat transfer coefficients on both sides into the equation. Also, where did you get the temperatures and dimensions?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask the authors why—if their samples were .01 m thick and 0.3 m on a side, and the temperature range (temperature difference?) was as high as 93°C—they report thermal conductivity values of <0.05 W/m-K when a naïve calculation would give 0.12 W/m-K.